# Fast in-subnet check on an IP address Strings (for both IPv4 and IPv6)

Tags: java, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I would like to do a fast in-subnet check on IP address strings. Casting the string to an integer would be a costly operation and it is desirable to get the code as fast as possible. The `SubnetUtils` library does not offer an IPv6 in-subnet check and the IPv4 version is rather slow.

Consider the following input:

`IP:     aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa
Subnet: aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa/128`

This should result into `true` since the IP address is included in the subnet.

What are the fastest ways of performing this computation in Java for both IPv4 and IPv6?

I will include and update benchmark results of the proposed solutions below:

```
=========================================================================================
Benchmark results - IP comparison (/24)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Input: IP, IP range (using CIDR) with a /24 subnet (50% is in-range, 50% is not in range)
Desired output: whether the IP address is in range.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Method 0: CIDRUtils.
Method 1: An optimized character-wise comparison using CIDRUtils and using Ineter for IPv6.
Method 2: SubnetUtils (IPv4 only, runs on half of the test cases).
Method 3: Ineter.
=========================================================================================
Number of runs: 1000000
Method 0 (on IPv4): 1228.0 ms
Method 1 (on IPv4): 459.0 ms
Method 2 (on IPv4): 844.0 ms
Method 3 (on IPv4): 963.0 ms
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Method 0 (on IPv6): 2203.0 ms
Method 1 (on IPv6): 845.0 ms
Method 2 (on IPv6): 0.0 ms
Method 3 (on IPv6): 543.0 ms

=========================================================================================
Benchmark results - Exact IP comparison (/128 and /32)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Input: IP, IP range (using CIDR) which is a /128 subnet for IPv6 and an /32 subnet for IPv4 (50% is in-range, 50% is not in range)
Desired output: whether the IP address is in range.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Method 0: CIDRUtils.
Method 1: An optimized character-wise comparison using CIDRUtils and using Ineter for IPv6.
Method 2: SubnetUtils (IPv4 only, runs on half of the test cases).
Method 3: Ineter.
=========================================================================================
Number of runs: 1000000
Method 0 (on IPv4): 602.0 ms
Method 1 (on IPv4): 336.0 ms
Method 2 (on IPv4): 690.0 ms
Method 3 (on IPv4): 626.0 ms
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Method 0 (on IPv6): 1607.0 ms
Method 1 (on IPv6): 499.0 ms
Method 2 (on IPv6): 0.0 ms
Method 3 (on IPv6): 530.0 ms
```

Comment: Try Ineter: https://github.com/maltalex/Ineter

Comment: Hi Malt, thank you for the suggestion. It worked quite well on my IPv6 benchmark. However, it was quite slow on IPv4 addresses compared to other methods.

Comment: Can you share your benchmark?

Comment: Its added now :)

Comment: The results are nice, but the code would be nicer :)

Comment: Sure: https://gist.github.com/kevin91nl/a131150599967b94c1ee95487a0dc074, I will publish "method 1" when more suggestions are added. CIDRUtils and SubnetUtils are available on GitHub.

Comment: Really all you need to do is a bitwise `AND` of each address with the network mask. If the two results are equal, then the are in the same network. It works exactly the same for both IPv4 and IPv6, the only difference being the (obvious) address and mask size difference between the two protocols.

Comment: @www.data-blogger.com Two points - 1. You shouldn't benchmark like that. Your results might be skewed by the JVM JIT. Use a benchmark harness such as JMH instead. 2. For Ineter, instead of creating the subnet from String, try using the IPv4Address instance you've just created and a 32 or 24 mask length. This may be a bit quicker than parsing the subnet string.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your benchmark with the [open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) for comparison with the others (CIDRUtils, SubnetUtils, and Ineter) mentioned above.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the IPAddress library. You also refer to "An optimized character-wise comparison using CIDRUtils and using Ineter for IPv6" but I do not have access to that code.

The code for IPAddress is simpler than for the others.  Unlike the others, the code is the same for both IPv4 and IPv6 and is just one line:

```
 boolean result = new IPAddressString(ipRange).prefixEquals(new IPAddressString(ip));
```

Feel free to try it yourself.

Your tests are:

- Test 1 and 2: IPv4 and IPV6 range (using CIDR) with a /24 subnet (50% is in-range, 50% is not in range)
- Test 3 and 4: IPv4 and IPv6 range (using CIDR) which is a /128 subnet for IPv6 and an /32 subnet for IPv4 (50% is in-range, 50% is not in range)

According to 10 separate runs of the benchmark on my macbook pro laptop, my results are showing:

- IPAddress is faster than CIDRUtils and SubnetUtils on all the tests (from 25% to 70% faster). IPAddress and Ineter are comparable in performance
- **IPAddress and Ineter comparison**:

  - **Test 1: IPAddress is 3% faster**, about 470 ms
  - **Test 2: Ineter is 7% faster**, about 520 ms
  - **Test 3: IPAddress is 32% faster**, about 278 ms
  - **Test 4: Ineter is 3% faster**, about 453 ms

Of course, mileage may vary on other machines.  However, according to my measurements it seems Ineter is slightly faster with IPv6, but slightly slower on IPv4 /24 subnet and much slower on full /32 IPv4 subnets.  However, IPAddress is a bit different in that the code is identical for IPv4 and IPv6 unlike Ineter which requires code specific to IPv4 or IPv6.